# How to get owner recovery phrase programmatically during keystore file generation?

Tags: dapp-development, password, keystore, recovery

I've generated keystore file by means of [keythereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum)

```
function generateAddress(cb) {
  var params = { keyBytes: 32, ivBytes: 16 };

  var dk = keythereum.create(params);

  keythereum.create(params, function (dk) {
    var options = {};
    var password = generatePassword();
    keythereum.dump(password, dk.privateKey, dk.salt, dk.iv, options, 
      function (keyObject) {
        cb(keyObject, password);
      }
    );
  });
}

function generatePassword() {
    var length = 8,
        charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
    retVal = "";
    for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
        retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

How to programmatically extract recovery phrase from generated keystore file or get it during the process of generation?

Comment: The password is not stored in the keystore file, it is only used to derive an encryption key to encrypt the private key. Look at the source of the dump function at https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum/blob/3ad46003f522c7ad6b6733746173898cff9c6bd5/index.js#L387.

Comment: @Ismael the question isn't about password, but about owner recovery phrase, you usually use to recover your wallet

Comment: There is no standard seed phrase algorithm in Ethereum. You need to specify which algorithm you want (BIP39, Electrum, Brain Wallet, etc)

Answer (score -1):

MyEtherWallet has the functionality you're looking for. It's open source at:

https://github.com/kvhnuke

https://www.myetherwallet.com

Comment: Can you provide some code example?